# Cannot publish AWS IoT messages from Raspberry Pi

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, aws-iot

I run a simple publish message from a Raspberry Pi. It seems that my device is connected to AWS IoT, but the message is not publishing and the `on_connect` and `on_publish` methods are not invoking.

Can anyone help figure out why?

```python
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt       
import ssl  
import json,time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):  
    print ("Subscriber Connection status code: "+str(rc))
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):  
    print(client, userdata, mid)
#Connect to AWS IoT
print("starting aws client")  
awsclient = mqtt.Client(client_id="raspberry",protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)  
awsclient.on_connect = on_connect  
awsclient.on_publish = on_publish  
awsclient.tls_set("./root-CA.pem",certfile="./575c6bc5b3-    certificate.pem.crt",keyfile="./575c6bc5b3-            private.pem.key",tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,ciphers=None)
awsclient.tls_insecure_set(True)  
awsclient.connect("a1e2evxrc4wz76.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 8883, 60)  
awsclient.loop_start()  

rc=0  
while rc == 0:  
   data={}  
   data['temp']='64'  
   data['humid']='65'  
   print(data)  
   payload = json.dumps(data)  
   print("Payload: " + payload)  
   awsclient.publish("Rasp/data", payload, qos=1)   
   time.sleep(10)  
print('rc: ' +str(rc))`
```

Comment: Are you sure that your certificate is correct? (BTW, probably not a good idea to make it public).  I guess that you have seen examples like [this one](http://www.awsomeblog.com/amazon-web-services-iot/).   Doesn't that `awsclient.connect` have a return value that you can check? For instance,  [CreateConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/APIReference/API_CreateConnection.html) does - both an HTTP response code and some JSON. It would be very strange if this one did not inform you of success or (reason for) failure.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking a question, but assuming it is "what do I check next" then you need to look at the `.connect` function. It is a [blocking call](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#connect-reconnect-disconnect) that waits for a `CONNACK` from the broker before calling `on_connect` with the result code.

If `on_connect` is not being called then the broker is not responding - maybe give it a bit more time. If execution is continuing after `.connect` then the `on_connect` reference is broken. Try stripping statements out until the `on_connect` function is successfully called. Only then can you start to debug your particular function.